# How remove default google map current location icon?

Tags: typescript, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I am creating hybrid app using **Ionic 2** & **Typescript**. I have added **cordova-plugin-googlemaps** plugin and added MAP in my page.

On view load I found the user location and adding the marker. My marker also added successfully. But default map current location icon (Blue dot) also added automatically. I wanted to hide/remove that.

Can anybody please let me know how we can hide this icon?

[image]

Comment: Show us some code, how is the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blue dot will be visible when you have set the "**myLocationButton**" value to true. Either remove it or set the value to false.

```
new GoogleMap('YOUR_MAP_ELEMENT', {
                'backgroundColor': 'white',
                'controls': {
                    'compass': true,
                    'myLocationButton': false,
                    'zoom': true
}});
```

Comment: If myLocationButton set to false then native Location button not appearing the screen & default dot also not visible. Thanks for sharing the helpful information.